# angularjs nested template issue with infdig error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

Here's my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/yr0belDSkouNdEb7eEAQ

Basically I have a group template that can exists within any given row of another group.
Group
     row
         condition
         group
           row
              group.....

Like that. But everything falls apart when you attempt to add a subgroup of a group.
Any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: It's in the link above